# Shiny app using lapply in server to generate renderUI but cant use an input to set the number

Tags: r, shiny

I created a reproducible example below. I posted the first one which works however the ui formatting does not update the same amount as the comp_panel. This is because the lapply(1:5 function(i) { .. }) toward the end of server is set to 5, but instead I need it set to input$compnum like the renderUI panel above. My second post of code is what I tried but that fails. How can I make the last lapply function use an input value?

**Working example but doesnt update properly.**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- fluidPage(navbarPage("Test",

                           tabPanel("Setup",
                                    fluidRow(align = "center",
                                             selectInput("compnum", NULL, choices = c(seq(2,20,1)), selected = 5)
                                    ), 
                                    fluidRow(align = "center",
                                             uiOutput("comp_panel")

                                    )
                           )
))

## server.r
server <- function(input, output) {

  # define component select panel for ui
  output$comp_panel <- renderUI({ 
    lapply(1:input$compnum, function(i) {
      column(5,
             radioButtons(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"ac",sep=""), "AC:",
                          c("a" = "A",
                            "b" = "B",
                            "c" = "C",
                            "d" = "D"), inline = TRUE),
             radioButtons(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"style",sep=""), "Style",
                          c("a1" = "A1",
                            "b1" = "B1",
                            "c1" = "C1",
                            "d1" = "D1",
                            "e1" = "E1",
                            "f1" = "F1"), inline = TRUE),
             uiOutput(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"select",sep="")),

             br()
      )
    })
  })

  cnum <- reactive ({
    input$comp_num
  })

  lapply(1:5, function(i) {
    output[[paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"select",sep="")]] <- renderUI({
      assign(paste("comp",i,sep=""), tryCatch(setNames("test1","Test1"),
                                              error = function(e) setNames("none","None Found")))
      selectInput(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"ticker",sep=""), paste("Component",i,sep=" "), get(paste("comp",i,sep="")))
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Not working example (tried to make the 1:5 go to 1:input$compnum**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)



ui <- fluidPage(navbarPage("Test",

                           tabPanel("Setup",
                                    fluidRow(align = "center",
                                             selectInput("compnum", NULL, choices = c(seq(2,20,1)), selected = 5)
                                    ), 
                                    fluidRow(align = "center",
                                             uiOutput("comp_panel")

                                    )
                           )
))

## server.r
server <- function(input, output) {

  # define component select panel for ui
  output$comp_panel <- renderUI({ 
    lapply(1:input$compnum, function(i) {
      column(5,
             radioButtons(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"ac",sep=""), "AC:",
                          c("a" = "A",
                            "b" = "B",
                            "c" = "C",
                            "d" = "D"), inline = TRUE),
             radioButtons(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"style",sep=""), "Style",
                          c("a1" = "A1",
                            "b1" = "B1",
                            "c1" = "C1",
                            "d1" = "D1",
                            "e1" = "E1",
                            "f1" = "F1"), inline = TRUE),
             uiOutput(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"select",sep="")),

             br()
      )
    })
  })

  cnum <- reactive ({
    input$comp_num
  })

  lapply(1:cnum(), function(i) {
    output[[paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"select",sep="")]] <- renderUI({
      assign(paste("comp",i,sep=""), tryCatch(setNames("test1","Test1"),
                                              error = function(e) setNames("none","None Found")))
      selectInput(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"ticker",sep=""), paste("Component",i,sep=" "), get(paste("comp",i,sep="")))
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `lapply` into an `observee` to be able to call a reactive expression. Try:

```
  observe({
        lapply(1:cnum(), function(i) {
                output[[paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"select",sep="")]] <- renderUI({
                        assign(paste("comp",i,sep=""), tryCatch(setNames("test1","Test1"),
                                                                error = function(e) setNames("none","None Found")))
                        selectInput(paste(paste("c",i,sep=""),"ticker",sep=""), paste("Component",i,sep=" "), get(paste("comp",i,sep="")))
                })
        })})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, its worked wonderfully. This helps in a lot of areas of my app, will read up on observer.